# How can I get the number of this expresion?

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, time-utility

Using `time`, I have got the part of the execution time of a script that I want but I need to divide it for one number (30), How can I do it?

```
....| awk '/^user/ {interest=($2)/(30);print "Time user divide by 30: " interest }'
```

In $2 I have the result 0m4.968s and I want to divide it by 30 and print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output `0m4.968s` looks like the default format for Bash's builtin `time`. To do meaningful calculations, the minutes would have to be converted to seconds. But it's easier to just change the output format. If we only care about the user time, setting `TIMEFORMAT=%U` should give just that, in seconds.

```
$ TIMEFORMAT=%U
$ time somecommand
4.968
```

Though piping the output of the builtin `time` is a bit awkward, since it wants to time the whole pipeline, but this should do:

```
$ (time somecommand ) 2>&1 | awk '{print $1 / 30}'
0.1656
```

Or if we have to parse the time in the original format, with minutes separated from seconds, maybe something like this:

```
$ echo "user 0m4.968s" | 
   awk '/user/ {split($2, a, "m"); secs = a[1]*60 + a[2]; print secs / 30}'
0.1656
```